# McNemar's for 1:N Matched Pairs (for N>1)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, paired-data, mcnemar-test

Sorry for the ignorant question, but I have 1:4 matched pairs data. I am trying to understand how one would run a McNemar's test in this situation, or if it would even be possible.

Each case is matched to 4 controls. I know if it were 1:1, McNemar's would be the correct 2x2 test, but I am trying to figure out how to generalize this given each case has 4 matches.

Thank you!

Comment: It might be easier to run an outcome model to test your hypothesis of interest; for example, if you are interested in the effect of a binary treatment on a binary outcome, logistic regression with a cluster-robust standard error tests the same hypothesis McNemar's test does and accounts for the matched data with no difficulty related to the 1:4 match. The `MatchIt` R package vignette has some example code for this.

Comment: Thank you! So you would effectively cluster at the "Match ID" level, I suppose, and then assess the difference between your binary variable (say cat1) where group 1 has your 4 matched patients and group 0 has your 1 control patient. I think this makes sense.

Comment: Yes exactly. You can use linear regression also if you want to interpret the risk difference, too.

Answer (score 1):

Cochran's *Q* test is to MnNemar's test as the repeated measures ANOVA is to the paired *t* test. In other words, Cochran's *Q* test is a test of the omnibus null hypothesis $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }p_1 = p_2 = \dots p_k$ for $k$ **blocked groups** with a binary outcome, with the alternative that at least one of the groups is sampled from a population with a different proportion than at least one other group.

Cochran's *Q* test is implemented in the [**cochranq**](https://alexisdinno.com/Software/index.shtml#cochranq) package in Stata (which implements choice of control of both false discovery rate and family-wise error rate in *post hoc* pairwise comparisons, and also updates with advances in non-asymptotic estimation by Barry and Mielke), and has been implemented in several packages in R.

**References**

Cochran, W. G. (1950). [The Comparison of Percentages in Matched Samples](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2332378). *Biometrika*, 37(3/4), 256–266.

Mielke, P. W., & Berry, K. J. (1995). [Nonasymptotic inferences based on Cochran’s *Q* test](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.2466/pms.1995.81.1.319). *Perceptual and Motor Skills*, 81, 319–322.

Comment: Thank you for this help. This makes sense generally, and I realize the alt hypothesis would apply, but it feels like there is a level of grouping that we know to be true that we lose when doing the Cochran's Q. Ie, we know group 1 (index group) is one group and then the 4 pairs belong to a separate group. We are curious is there a difference between these two binary groups. It seems like treating all 5 of those groups as equal is not exactly what we hope to test. We aren't interested in whether there is a difference between any of the 4 control groups rel to each other. Does this make sense?

Comment: @thanksForTheHelp12 It makes sense, but what you describe is a common use case for omnibus tests. For example, repeated measures ANOVA to look for evidence of a difference between groups in an omnibus test. **If you reject the null** then you proceed to *post hoc* pairwise tests. Sometimes researchers perform all possible pairwise tests, and sometimes they only perform, say, group A versus all other groups (e.g., using McNemar's or Cochran's *Q* on two groups again for *post hoc* tests). You would then adjust for multiple comparisons, e.g., using the Benjamini-Hochberg false discovery method.

Comment: @thanksForTheHelp12 Also, I think "It seems like treating all 5 of those groups as equal is not exactly what we hope to test" is inorrect: your null hypothesis is $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }p_{\text{treat}} = p_{\text{control 1}} = p_{\text{control 2}} = p_{\text{control 3}} = p_{\text{control 4}}$, right?

Comment: Thank you! 

I would sort of view the Null as treat=pcontrol where p control is essentially one group (pcontrol1 + pcontrol2 + pcontrol3 + pcontrol4). As I view it, I have two groups, that happen to be different sizes. I care is group 1 (ptreat) different from group 2 (pcontrol). I am not interested in testing whether pcontrol1/2/3/4 are all equal to each other - they are not distinct groups to my mind.

Comment: @thanksForTheHelp12 I think you are unfamiliar with the idea of repeated measures designs and tests, which are **precisely** for the kinds of circumstances you describe. "Not distinct groups" implies $p_{\text{control 1 }} = p_{\text{control 2}} = p_{\text{control 3}} = p_{\text{control 4}}$, while specifically modeling your blocking/matching.

Comment: Very familiar with repeated measures designs, and Noah's answer above makes sense to me and is what I'll roll with. I think we are just getting lost in translation on the forum. Anyway, I appreciate you taking the time to help greatly!